# why we have to make function explicitly mutating in Structures in Swift?

Tags: swift, struct, structure

Why we have to make function explicitly mutating in Structures in Swift? 
I want to understand behind the scene concept of this.

Can anyone explain how does it work?

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
    mutating func moveBy(x deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double) {
        x += deltaX
        y += deltaY
    }
}
var somePoint = Point(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
somePoint.moveBy(x: 2.0, y: 3.0)
print("The point is now at (\(somePoint.x), \(somePoint.y))")
// Prints "The point is now at (3.0, 4.0)"
```

As per Apple Documentation "if you need to modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change) its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure when the method ends. The method can also assign a completely new instance to its implicit self property, and this new instance will replace the existing one when the method ends."

Why it's not allowed to change properties of structures(value type) without mutating where as same is not the case with reference type?

Comment: Not related to your question but I would make all properties constants and if you need to change it just instantiate a new point based on it instead of mutating.

Answer (score 0):

Structs are value types and hence when you mutate any instance properties of a struct, you actually mutate the struct instance itself. This is why when you have a function that mutates any instance properties of the struct, you explicitly need to mark that function mutating, because calling the function mutates the struct instance itself too.

For more information, you should read the [Methods chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html#ID235) of the Swift Book, because it explains this behaviour in detail.